# PHP: Undefined index when try to upload

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

Just started to learn PHP codes, trying to test the upload function but end up failing. I am currently using WampServer and everything is local. Here are my codes.
index.html:

```
<body>
  <div data-role='header'>
    <h1>Photo upload</h1>
  </div>

  <form action='upload_file.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' name='myfile'><p>
    <input type='submit' name='Upload' value='Upload'>
  </form>
</body>
```

upload_file.php:

```
<?php
echo $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
?>
```

After selecting a file and pressing the 'Upload' button at index.html, it ends up giving 'Undefined Index' error.

Any helps or advices are appreciated.

Comment: maybe the file didn't upload right, what var_dump($_FILES) gives you?

Comment: Make sure you upload a file that is allowed by your server, for example check if the file is of less size than upload_max_filesize in your config file

Comment: *Unrelated*: Why is there a floating `<p>` element?

Comment: @tinyByte The var_dump gave me array(0)

Comment: @Kleskowy Below is my upload config in php.ini:
file_uploads = On
upload_tmp_dir = "d:/wamp/tmp"
upload_max_filesize = 10M

Comment: @h2ooooooo sorry it's some leftovers, gonna remove it

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow right syntax for upload a file. Please see the [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: Hmm, I just want to test if the server is able to receive the file. Thought my codes should at least print out the file name for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if it's empty or not:

```
if (isset($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]))
{
    // File present
}
```